# How to increase ajax data post limit in .net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

In .net core web application, when the ajax post data is larger, the ajax post throws 404 error. Is there any possible way to send more data through ajax by increasing its limit. Same ajax code supports when data is less

[image]

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addnewrelease',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        timeout: validationMessages.timeoutCount,
        data: {
            'releaseName': releaseName.value,
            'productId': productId,
            'startDate': startDate.value,
            'releaseDate': endDate.value,
            'codeFreeze': codeFreeze.value,
            'duration': duration.value,
            'releaseType': type,
            'releaseVersion': version.value,
            'releaseTemplate': template,
            'phases': phases
        },
```

Comment: You're sending a GET request...?

Comment: Basically, the fact that you get 404 has nothing to do with the size of your query string, rather with route mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
type: "GET"
```

to

```
type: "POST"
```